# Performance issue with Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular6

Good night!
I'm developing a angular 5 aplication, right now it is looking like this:

```
----child module 1
      ---child module
      ---child module (.....)
----child module
root module
```

I'll try to explain my issue right below, hopefully i'll be understood:

I'm using lazy loading already in all of my modules, excluding the core module of the application. 
When i enter the lazy loaded module **child module 1** (through the "localhost/child-1" url) i have the following child routing (i'm using RouterModule.forChild):

```
const marketplaceRoutes: Routes = [

//Public routes
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent},
```

So **HomeComponent** is loaded "right away". What is happening is that from the moment my app has entered in the **child 1 module** it takes more than two seconds to enter and initialize the **HomeComponent**. But for example, if i'm loading components of and from the root module this delay is not happening. Do you have any ideas of why this delay is happening? I've checked my network requests and it's not the network requests that are delaying the loading of the page. I'll put a screenshot below:

[image]

I'm not saying the delay is "not supposed to happen", i just wanted to know what is going on during this seconds of delay

Any help wouold be appreciated :)

Comment: Does it take that long every time you load `HomeComponent` or only that one instance?

Comment: Did you try to record the page load using the performance tab to see what is going on during that time?

Comment: @Dummy Hey! It takes that long only on that one instance

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I've done it now and like 75% of the seconds were used in scripting